# Is there any recommendation to bring up error messages from Data Access Layer to the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, architecture, custom-error-handling

I'd like to know what are the best practices, or the best / elegant way to bring up error message from Data Access Layer (or other layers) to the View.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, my project has multiple layers, such as:

- MyApp.Web
- MyApp.Business
- MyApp.Repository
- MyApp.DAL

I have two types of "error messages" that I'd like to bring up to the IHM:

- Errors generated by Exceptions: exception is logged and a human friendly error message is displayed.
- Business errors: for example, an action needs a customer has at least 3 invoices and he only has 2.

In another project, here is what I did:

*Controller*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    //...
    ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel();

    BusinessLayer businessLayer = new businessLayer()
    businessLayer.Edit( /* some parameters */, out errorModel)

    TempData[Error] = errorModel
}
```

*View*

```
@{
    var errorModel = TempData[Error]
}

/* if error model is not null, display the error correctly */
```

In every layer, all my methods have a `out ErrorModel` variable which is filled in `try / catch` blocks, or because of business failure and I definitely don't like that.

I found a lot of answers on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=best%20way%20error%20handling) or Stack Overflow, but all focuses on how to catch errors.

*My question goes further: Once catched, how to bring errors up from the layer it occurs to the view on an elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach of that is throwing exceptions in all layers and handle them in the top layer (presentation - controller actions). Exception is one type of method result and you don't need to specify it in method signature. The approach of passing out errorModel is not good because every method should return it and every method should have try catch block.

In business layer you can have some business exceptions which are derived from Exception class and have some additional information. Or you can use general ApplicationException class.
So, your controller can look like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        try
        {
            businessLayer.Edit( /* some parameters */)
            return Ok();
        }
         catch(BadAcctionException)
        {
            TempData[Error] = "Bad business operation";
            return BadBusinessAction();
        }
        catch(ApplicationException ex)
        {
            TempData[Error] = ex.Message;
            return Fail();
        }
    }
```

and inside businessLayer.Edit you throw an exception if something wrong is.

Comment: That looks interesting. So according to you, I "only" have to try / catch any exception in all my layers, then treat them in the "main" try catch in my controller ?

Comment: Try/catch only in the top layer (presentation) - handling errors. In another layers you can throw an exception if you need.

Comment: And you can try/catch exceptions in lower layers if you don't want to expose some exceptions to the top layer. For instance if you don't want passing SqlConnectionException inside DAL to Web layer you can try/catch this exception in Business layer and throwing there something like CriticalAppException

Comment: @VasylZvarydchuk What if in your DAL, you do a check to see if something already exists before inserting to share the same Connection and prevent the delay of closing and reopening. So in the DAL, you want to convey to the View at some point the item already exists in the database. This would be considered an exception too?